Disable automatic undindent for `in` keyword for OCaml in VSCode
I am programming in OCaml using VSCode, but each time I begin a line with the in keyword, the editor automatically unindent the line. This is really annoying and I would like to disable this particular feature.
For example, if I want to write a line incr i, the indentation is broken.
I already searched in the VSCode options, using keywords "format" or "OCaml", but to no success.

Could you give some snippets of code showing what is the produced indentation, and what is it that you would want to have instead?
